# Manually Firing ngx-sweetalert2 from code

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

The following code can fire a modal when the button is clicked

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-3 trans-3"
        [swal]="swalDeleteConfig"
        (confirm)="deleteItem($event)">
    Delete
</button>
```

passing the appropriate options object

```
private swalDeleteConfig: SweetAlertOptions = {
    title: 'Are you sure you want to delete?',
    confirmButtonText: "Delete",
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',

    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn',

    type: "question",

    customClass: {
        actions: "mt-5 mb-5"
    }
}
```

This is done without specifying the HTML for the modal. How can I manually fire this event in response to something? For example, a toast after an async operation is finished.

Comment: have you tried `swalDeleteConfig.show( )` ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a method of SweetAlertOptions

Comment: `@ViewChild('deleteSwal') private deleteSwal: SwalComponent` you need to add this to your `.ts` file to show your dialogue from `.ts` file. check documentation: https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2